# Offset UISlider Min/Max value images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uislider

I'm trying to offset the x/y position of a UISlider's min and max value images. 
Currently, I'm sublcassing UISlider and am setting the maximum value image like this:

```
[self setMaximumValueImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle_with_plus"]];
```

However, I need this image to be closer to the actual UISlider and have little control over visual assets on this project. I've tried using

```
- (CGRect)maximumValueImageRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
```

However, I'm my min/max value images may change size dynamically so I'm not sure how to properly implement it in this case. Is there a different way to move the asset?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no other way to reposition the minimum or maximum value images.  `maximumValueImageRectForBounds:` gets invoked every time the slider lays out its subviews, and laying out the subviews happens whenever you change the `maximumValueImage`, so it is sufficient to do:

```
@implementation MyCustomSlider

- (CGRect)maximumValueImageRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
  CGRect r = [super maximumValueImageRectForBounds:bounds];
  r.origin.x -= 3;
  return r;
}

@end
```