# How to remove the space between UISlider and Minimum Image

Tags: swift, xcode, uislider

I would like to remove the space / offset at the beginning of the UISlider and join it with the custom minimum image that I have.

[image]

Is it possible to do it programmatically in Swift?

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032866/offset-uislider-min-max-value-images), but it's old and it's for Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, I looked at the answer you tagged, and made something up for you on playground. Not sure if it works precisely for your case, but the key is to look into the methods of `UISlider` that you can override [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uislider)

```
import UIKit

class SomeController: UIViewController {
    let slider = MyCustomSlider()
    //etc...
}

class MyCustomSlider: UISlider {
    override func maximumValueImageRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var r = super.maximumValueImageRect(forBounds: bounds)
        r.origin.x -= 3
        return r
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. And you can also include r.origin.y to adjust the vertical position

Comment: You can change the maximumValue... to minimumValue to reflect the correct image that I have asked ;)

Comment: yuppp! Didn't know what you needed exactly lol but you got the gist of it! :)